# Install MySQLdb on a Mac

Tags: python, mysql

I have Python 32 bits, I installed MySQL Community server 32 bits and I'm trying to install MySQLdb for Python.
I run

> easy_install mysql-python

and I have this error

```
> easy_install mysql-python
Searching for mysql-python
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.4b5
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5.zip#md5=4f645ed23ea0f8848be77f25ffe94ade
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.4b5.zip
Running MySQL-python-1.2.4b5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/ke/ke8HKCuzGB4LMCJ1eIAGqk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-W_yT0e/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5/egg-dist-tmp-GjLaFB
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
Extracting in /var/folders/ke/ke8HKCuzGB4LMCJ1eIAGqk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-W_yT0e/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5/temp/tmpOVVY_R
Now working in /var/folders/ke/ke8HKCuzGB4LMCJ1eIAGqk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-W_yT0e/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5/temp/tmpOVVY_R/distribute-0.6.28
Building a Distribute egg in /private/var/folders/ke/ke8HKCuzGB4LMCJ1eIAGqk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-W_yT0e/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5
/private/var/folders/ke/ke8HKCuzGB4LMCJ1eIAGqk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-W_yT0e/MySQL-python-1.2.4b5/distribute-0.6.28-py2.6.egg
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Any idea on why gcc-4.0 cannot be found? I have Xcode and gcc 4.2.1 installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mountain Lion ,Your problem seems to do with not having xcode command line tools installed, if you install them first from xcode then this should work

Comment: I'm on Snow Leopard. It looks like I can't install mysqldb because I need to compile a file called _mysql.c. When I try to compile it with gcc 4.2.2, I get an error...

Answer (score 0):

how to: `pip install mysql-python` on `python 2.7`
in order to `>>>import MySQLdb`

**I FOLLOWED ALL THESE STEPS AND I GOT IT WORKING**

**For brew in case it wont let you update due to permissions.**

```
chgrp -R admin /usr/local
chmod -R g+w /usr/local
chgrp -R admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
chmod -R g+w /Library/Caches/Homebrew

brew update
brew doctor  ## <--i did not use that
brew upgrade

ALSO I IGNORED THE Xcode update error

brew install mysql

pip install mysql-python
```

when i tried to import MySQLdb it threw me some errors so i followed the advise offered by the link bellow.

```
sudo ln -s /Users/$USERNAME/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
sudo ln -s /Users/$USERNAME/anaconda/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

**THE LINKS I USED**

[lib... issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585269/mamp-python-mysqldb-issue-path-to-libssl-1-0-0-dylib-changing-once-python-file)

[home bre update permission issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42127/homebrew-permissions-multiple-users-needing-to-brew-update)

[install mysql with brew](http://blog.joefallon.net/2013/10/install-mysql-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/)