# MAMP Python-MySQLdb issue: Path to libssl.1.0.0.dylib changing once Python file called

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mamp

I'm trying to use python MySQLdb to access my MySQL database on my MAMP server.

When I initially tried to call a Python file with python-sql to access my database on MAMP I got the `image not found` error regarding the `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` library

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "desktopsql.py", line 3, in <module>
    import _mysql as ms
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__

  ImportError: 
   dlopen(/Users/username/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-
  10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): 

  Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib

  Referenced from: 
   /Users/username/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so

  Reason: image not found
```

So I fixed it to a certain extent by changing the `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` path using
 `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/username/anaconda/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it has to be done for every folder I wish to execute the Python file in.

So when I try to execute the Python file through `PHP` on my MAMP webpage I get the error again, and I can't use my makeshift fix this time to cover it up.

I have tried to fix it further using `install_name_tool` to change the false library location `/Users/username/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so` to where it is actually stored in `/Users/username/anaconda/lib/`

```
sudo install_name_tool -change 
libssl.1.0.0.dylib 
/Users/username/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib 
/Users/username/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
```

After doing so I use `otool -L` to see the status of what I've changed and the result states that the file path **has** certainly changed to the correct location.

```
otool -L 
/Users/username/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so

    /Users/username/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib 
    (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

**However** when I run the python file again, I get the `image not found` error. Upon running `otool -L` again the result shows that the file path has reverted back again.

```
/Users/username/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so:

    libssl.1.0.0.dylib 
    (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

So it changes to the correct location until I run the python file and it's back again to what it was before.

Why is this happening? Is there something I can do to make it maintain what I've changed it to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I discovered I should be working with the `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` file in `/usr/lib`, not the file that was mentioned by the error, which was `Users/$USERNAME/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so` in my case.

I created a symlink to where `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` should be referenced from, (`/Users/$USERNAME/anaconda/lib/` for me), using

`sudo ln -s /Users/$USERNAME/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib`

and, once that's done, the same for `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`, as it threw the same error.

`sudo ln -s /Users/$USERNAME/anaconda/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`

As a side note when listing the files in `/usr/bin` these two are listed as `libss.dylib` and `libcrypto.dylib`.

Comment: Trying to install https://github.com/cvondrick/vatic on Mac OS X and I also came across this problem. The solution here worked perfectly.

Comment: If using OSX El Capitan, /usr/lib is write protected by default (even in sudo). To turn this off, follow [these](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) steps